# Отображение многостроковых r-строк

Tags: python, строки, print

В интерактивном интерпретаторе я завожу многострочную строку и пытаюсь ее вывести.

```
>>> s = r'''Hello my
... friend'''
>>> s
... 'Hello my\nfriend'
>>> print(s)
Hello my
friend
```

Так как это r-строка, интерактивный интерпретатор преобразует перенос строки в символ '\n' и выводит текст в одну строку. Здесь вопросов нет. Все логично.
Однако в случае с вызовом функции print(), мы видим что текст разбился на 2 строки.

**Подскажите, в чем причина такого поведения функции print()?**

Comment: Интерактивный интерпретатор по сути делает `print(repr(s))`, чтобы показать строку со всеми управляющими символами. А простая печать отрабатывает эти управляющие символы.

Comment: Знак r заменяет перевод строки не на \n а на \\n тоесть буквально он экранирует все ескейп последовательности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В дополнение к уже данным ответам.

Поиграйтесь с методами строк. Пример

```py
>>> s.__repr__()
"'Hello my\\nfriend'"
>>> repr(s)
"'Hello my\\nfriend'"
>>> s.__str__()
'Hello my\nfriend'
```

Можно прочитать про метод [repr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr).

Переведу различие между `str` и `repr` из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

> Функция `str` предназначена для возврата представлений, которые удобочитаемы для человека, в то время как `repr` предназначена для генерирования представлений, которые может прочитать интерпретатор. (или вызовет SyntaxError, если нет эквивалентного синтаксиса). Для объектов, которые не имеют конкретного представления удобного для  человека, str() вернет то же значение, что и repr().

Answer (score 0):

Вы фактически выполняете `print ('Hello my\nfriend')`.
Вот он и выводит 2 строки. Управляющий символ им управляет:-)
Это же уже не r-строка.

А вот `print (r'Hello my\nfriend')` выведет вам одну строку, так как тут - r-строка.

Comment: В этом то и вопрос.  Переменная s изначально ссылается на  r-строку. Но в при вызове print() r-строка вдруг превращается в обычную.

Видимо дело в многострочной строке. Потому что код: 
`s = r'hello\world'
print(s) #hello\nworld`

Отображается корректно.

Comment: Полагаю, неверно считать, что r-строка хранится как-то по-особому. Я вижу, что это просто указание интерпретатору (а, скорее, компилятору), как преобразовать вводимые данные. И нет необходимости далее хранить их в таком виде.

Comment: Кстати, ответы, которые были полезны, можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).